# How to grab fingerprints from AET65 fingerprint reader in java

Tags: java, fingerprint, biometrics

I am a beginner in biometric fingerprint area, now i am doing a project on fingerprint recognition. am using AET65 smart card reader with fingerprint sensor. I have found API of AET65 in the internet, it has so many functions like ABS_STATUS ABSGrab,ABS_STATUS ABSEnrol etc. But i am not able to find any examples of these functions. Is these functions are useful  to grab fingerprint from the reader, if not can anyone please help me to find how to grab images from fingerprint reader